# Blender 2.82 crashing while trying to load HDRI for the world

Tags: hdri

I was trying to create a simple scene and for the world, I wanted to add a HDRI. Here, I ran into a roadblock. Blender 2.82 crashes while loading the HDRI. I tried multiple HDRI files, each with differently resolution.

I am running Blender 2.82 in Manjaro, Linux 5.6.8-1 64-bit kernel with AMDGPU open source drivers. My hardware is AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Vega 8 Integrated graphics and 16GB RAM. This is a laptop and I do not have any discreet GPU.

I believe its a problem with the Drivers because, if I download blender portable edition from the main site and run the Software rendering version of Blender, everything works but performance is very bad.

I tried Blender from different sources, I installed from the package manager, from the main website, from the AURs but all seems to be giving the same error. I tried with Linux kernel version 5.4 also, but it gave the same error.

The error message is given below

```
[ajith@SoulCubeLaptop prakriya_oms]$ blender
Read prefs: /home/ajith/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'
Read blend: /home/ajith/Works/Graphics/3D/Umbrella_in_the_rain/umbrella_in_the_rain.blend
Writing: /tmp/umbrella_in_the_rain.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The log file contents are given below

```
[ajith@SoulCubeLaptop prakriya_oms]$ cat /tmp/umbrella_in_the_rain.crash.txt 
# Blender 2.82 (sub 7), Commit date: 2020-03-12 05:06, Hash 375c7dc4caf4
bpy.context.space_data.shader_type = 'WORLD'  # Property
bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="//stone_alley_02_4k.hdr", directory="/home/ajith/Works/Graphics/3D/Umbrella_in_the_rain/", files=[{"name":"stone_alley_02_4k.hdr", "name":"stone_alley_02_4k.hdr"}], relative_path=True, show_multiview=False)  # Operator

# backtrace
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x34) [0x5650e7d71a34]
blender(+0xed6cf5) [0x5650e5ad7cf5]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3bd70) [0x7f0248e92d70]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x7a6364) [0x7f0221ef9364]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x7a66ae) [0x7f0221ef96ae]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x7e5b30) [0x7f0221f38b30]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x4f627c) [0x7f0221c4927c]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x4fa587) [0x7f0221c4d587]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x4fb958) [0x7f0221c4e958]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xe703c4) [0x7f02225c33c4]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xdd17c0) [0x7f02225247c0]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xe76cdb) [0x7f02225c9cdb]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xe66705) [0x7f02225b9705]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x9c069a) [0x7f022211369a]
/usr/lib/libGLX_mesa.so.0(+0x3823d) [0x7f023db3d23d]
/usr/lib/libGLX.so.0(+0x14c23) [0x7f02463e4c23]
/usr/lib/libGLX.so.0(+0x1b975) [0x7f02463eb975]
blender(_ZN16GHOST_ContextGLX22activateDrawingContextEv+0x1e) [0x5650e64b6e8e]
blender(wm_window_reset_drawable+0x49) [0x5650e5cbf2c9]
blender(DRW_opengl_context_disable_ex+0x66) [0x5650e5d7cc96]
blender(wm_draw_update+0x4c9) [0x5650e5c98ed9]
blender(WM_main+0x34) [0x5650e5c96e14]
blender(main+0x344) [0x5650e5aa9154]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f0248e7e023]
blender(_start+0x2e) [0x5650e5ad40fe]
```

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with your graphics driver (`radeonsi_dri.so`). Please try to update your graphics driver if you haven't already. It seems that there are plenty people experiencing issues with Vega 8 on Linux.

Comment: I am on the latest kernel for Manjaro. I will try to get AMDGPU PRO drivers working in the laptop. Or go back to an older version of the linux kernel. Meanwhile if someone found a workaround, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an update. I tried downgrading kernels all the way till 4.19, but the problem persists with Blender 2.82. I tried different version numbers for blender, and it seems to be stable in blender 2.80